# When I am trying to render a donut it just does a checkered background and then crashes

Tags: rendering

I have already tried putting it into a new document. I haven't used Blender before this and have been following a tutorial.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's not much information in this question. Could you upload your blender project file so I can check it out?

Comment: it looks like particles make the last blender version crash, it may be the problem here, what version do you use?

Comment: version 2.93 I believe. Also running on an early 2015 macbook air, if that helps.